# How do I get my webserver to restart without exiting Cypress

Tags: node.js, cypress, wrangler

I have a wrangler webserver which runs a couple of ports (e.g. 3100-3102). I have a Cypress integration test server wrapped in a Node script (for parallelisation in an azure pipeline).

The wrangler webserver is prone to the [legendary and ongoing](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/worker-throws-network-connection-lost/287314/12) `Network connection lost.` issue. This delays the integration tests and my devs have to manually restart them. I'd like to automate that process.

- Detecting the failure was easy enough when I wrapped it in a node script and checked for that error.
- `spawned.kill()` results in the ports still being in use.
- Running `lsof -t -i tcp:3101-3102 | xargs kill` freed up the ports but then the Cypress server shut down in response. I do not want Cypress to shut down.
- I'm happy to `SIGSTOP` the Cypress process and `SIGCONT` when the webserver restarts so that it can run all the integration tests with minimum delay.

How can I restart my webserver without Cypress shutting down?